# How to use CONSTRAINT CHECK in SQLDEVELOPER on a specific DATE?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to set a CONSTRAINT on column `Nr_AnoLetivo` which is a DATE, which only can be NOT NULL AND greater than the year 2000.

I've been trying this:

```
CREATE TABLE Classe(
  Cd_Classe     NUMBER(8),   
  Nr_AnoLetivo  NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT CLASSE_NR_ANOLETIVO_NN NOT NULL,
  Cd_Escola     NUMBER(5),
  Cd_Grau       NUMBER(2),
  Nr_Serie      NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT CLASSE_NR_SERIE_NN NOT NULL, 
  Sg_Turma      VARCHAR2(2) CONSTRAINT CLASSE_SG_TURMA_NN NOT NULL,
  Cd_Periodo    NUMBER(2),
  CONSTRAINT CLASSE_CD_CLASSE_PK PRIMARY KEY (CD_CLASSE),
  CONSTRAINT CLASSE_NR_ANOLETIVO_CK CHECK (NR_ANOLETIVO IN DATE ('2000/01/01')),
  CONSTRAINT ESCOLA_CD_ESCOLA_FK FOREIGN KEY (CD_ESCOLA) REFERENCES Escola (CD_ESCOLA),
  CONSTRAINT GRAU_CD_GRAU_FK FOREIGN KEY (CD_GRAU) REFERENCES Grau (CD_GRAU),
  CONSTRAINT PERIODO_CD_PERIODO_FK FOREIGN KEY (CD_PERIODO) REFERENCES Periodo (CD_PERIODO)
);
```

And the Error message is:

> 936. 00000 - "missing expression"

Something tells me this error is generated by the DATE row and I don't get it why.

Can anyone tell why is this happening?

Comment: For one thing, dates are written like `date '2000-01-01'`, not `date ('2000/01/01')`. (But then `nr_anoletivo` is defined as a number and not a date anyway - see Littlefoot's answer.) I also think it's good practice to define FK constraints as part of the column, as then you can skip the datatypes to let them inherit from the parent.

Comment: Also, SQL Developer is a desktop tool for working with Oracle databases. It doesn't have anything to do with your syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You got it wrong.

If you declared `NR_ANOLETIVO` column as `NUMBER(4)`, it seems that you expect **year only** in that column (such as 1957, 1998, 2010, etc.), not the whole date (such as 16.09.2018 (dd.mm.yyyy)).

Therefore, setting a constraint to check some *date* value is wrong - you should check that value you put into that column is larger than 2000. Something like this (your code, simplified):

```
SQL> create table classe
  2    (cd_classe    number(8) constraint pk_cla primary key,
  3     --
  4     nr_anoletivo number(4) constraint ch_nra_2k check (nr_anoletivo > 2000)
  5                            not null,
  6     --
  7     cd_grau      number(2));

Table created.

SQL> insert into classe (cd_classe, nr_anoletivo, cd_grau) values (1, 1990, 23);
insert into classe (cd_classe, nr_anoletivo, cd_grau) values (1, 1990, 23)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_NRA_2K) violated


SQL> insert into classe (cd_classe, nr_anoletivo, cd_grau) values (2, 2018, 33);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

If you really meant to check the full date, then you should modify datatype column (to `DATE`), as well as the constraint:

```
SQL> create table classe
  2    (cd_classe    number(8) constraint pk_cla primary key,
  3     --
  4     nr_anoletivo date      constraint ch_nra_2k check (nr_anoletivo > date '2000-01-01')
  5                            not null,
  6     --
  7     cd_grau      number(2));

Table created.

SQL> insert into classe (cd_classe, nr_anoletivo, cd_grau) values (1, date '1990-12-25', 23);
insert into classe (cd_classe, nr_anoletivo, cd_grau) values (1, date '1990-12-25', 23)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_NRA_2K) violated


SQL> insert into classe (cd_classe, nr_anoletivo, cd_grau) values (2, date '2018-09-16', 33);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: when you answer a question and littlefoot beats you by 18 seconds :)

Comment: Type faster, (@that) Jeff :)

Comment: I love how we race to provide GOOD answers only to have the person who wrote the question take days to respond, if ever

Comment: Exactly. Sad, but true, @that Jeff.

Comment: @littlefoot thank you, it worked like a charm. my professor was actually looking for the year only so the first answer was perfect. Thank you very much!